# Wireless authentication asked when using nmcli to restart wifi on a connection shared to all users

Tags: wireless, lubuntu, network-manager

I am building a little kiosk computer that connects to Wifi. 
I have 2 users, one (admin) with Admin rights and one (kiosk) without anything. On the one with admin rights, I create a new wifi connection through network-manager and tick the box "available to all users".

The kiosk account is configured to auto-login (I am on Lubuntu 14.04 LTS). When the computer boots, there's no problem, the connection happens smoothly.

My issue is that the wifi drops sometimes, and I have a cron that reboots the computer when the connection disappears. I'd like to just restart the wifi instead, but when I do, it prompts for the Wifi password... and then, **just pressing escape will still make the connection happen**

I am using this to restart the wifi:

```
nmcli nm wifi off && sleep 5 && ncmli nm wifi on
```

Any idea on how to avoid that wireless authentication pop-up ?

Thank you very much